# .env in my git repo

Tags: heroku, github, environment-variables, bitbucket

My .env is stored on my git repo, which gets published to heroku and bitbucket.

I know that publishing .env github is bad, but
since bitbucket is private, and heroku is meant for production, are any of my secret keys/values in jeopardy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bitbucket repo is private, so anything you store there is only visible to the people you explicitly authorize to access your repo, unless, of course, bitbucket get hacked...

You need to configure your environment variables for Heroku anyway via "heroku config", so the fact that they are also in your git repo doesn't really compromise them any further. Again, only people with explicit access permissions should be able to see your Heroku config vars or access your Heroku git repo.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, no. But I would not rely on storing secrets into a repository made to be replicated (ie a git repo)

At least consider "[Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)":

> The traditional approach for handling such config vars is to put them under source - in a properties file of some sort. This is an error-prone process, and is especially complicated for open source apps which often have to maintain separate (and private) branches with app-specific configurations.
>
> A better solution is to use environment variables, and keep the keys out of the code. On a traditional host or working locally you can set environment vars in your bashrc file. On Heroku, you use config vars.
>
> Use the Heroku CLI’s config, `config:set`, `config:get` and `config:unset` to manage your config vars